How to convince professors for undergrad research when you don't have enough credits?
I am a BSc physics student who wants to be a mathematician. I would like to do an undergraduate research project in mathematics. I can't take any pure math courses apart from real analysis at my university, but I have self-learned group theory, abstract linear algebra, real analysis and basic point set topology. (I have solved most exercises in popular textbooks in these topics.)
How do I convince professors to take me in, when I don't have math credits to prove my knowledge and passion? Will online courses (that have offline exams) work?

Given what you have learned so far, you are several years away from being able to do any meaningful mathematical research. If you had taken some combinatorics classes and the professor were working in the combinatorics area, then it would have made a difference.

"(I have solved most exercises in popular textbooks in these topics)." How do you know your so0lutions/proofs are all correct ? Suggestion for you, post some of your solutions/proofs on Math.SE and ask experts on that site to check them.

@Nobody, I cross check and learn from solution manuals. But I get your point

@Moishe Kohan, I have taken a basic combinatorics class. Also, do you think graph theory is accessible to me?

I have just edited your post to remove the first question. Questions should focus on only one issue  and we don’t cover research content here. If you feel I went too far you can always [edit] the question back in again.

Yes, graph theory requires very little math background. But you need an advisor who specializes in this subject. And, as others suggested, you should talk to this professor in person. It is far from clear they would take you even if you have the required background.

Can you clarify what the problem is exactly? Why are you talking about convincing professors with additional math credits? Why this approach is the only option you consider? Did you talk to the professors and they mandated you to convince them by taking additional math courses? Have you talked to the professors and your undergrad advisor at all? What exactly did they say? How did you approach these discussions? How did these discussions go? Do you know how to talk to people? Do you have experience solving any problem by just talking to people?

In your another question, you mentioned "I can only take introductory group theory and real anaysis from the math dept.". If you got A from both courses, you should not have too much  problem to convince the profs for you to join a research project.

If you want to convince someone of something, you have to sit down with them. It is nearly impossible to do it remotely or by mail.
Find a professor in a field you'd like to explore and go visit them. Express your need, and tell them you'd be happy to try to demonstrate your knowledge, perhaps by taking an oral (or written) exam for one of the core courses. If you have written anything meaningful in the field, offer to let them see it.
I doubt that online courses, with some rare exceptions, will help you much as it can be difficult to trust them or their credentials (Open University UK is an exception).
I also wonder why switching majors, or even universities, isn't one of your best options. It will take time to switch, but maybe less time than switching after completing a physics degree. And note that pure and applied math are vastly different. You could explore that with a math professor in a sit down also.
And, if it is applied math that appeals, the right physics professor could probably get you started without the need to switch.

Academia differs highly between countries, and between individual universities. So not all of my advice might apply -- but I'll answer from my perspective as a mathematics professor in the United States.
If you asked me to take you on as a research student, I would ask -- why are you studying physics, if your goal is to become a mathematician? And why is it you can't take any pure math courses other than real analysis? At my university, you would be able to (1) switch your major to mathematics, (2) double major in physics and math, or (3) keep your physics major but take as many math courses as you would like. If you wanted to do research with me, I would ask you to do one of the above -- and in particular to get more formal training in math.
If real analysis is the only pure math course offered, and there is no math major available... then that is a possible sign of a weak mathematics department, and I'm not sure if this university is a good place to realize your ambitions.
If you can't add a mathematics major, or take other math courses, because of administrative roadblocks... then I'm not sure.
But if the obstacles are something you can resolve, I'd encourage you to try and do so.
In general, I don't encourage students to "work around the system", because the system is (while not perfect) designed to help students and works fairly well. And I would probably be reluctant to mentor a research student, if I did not have more infrastructure around me (e.g. a strong department that offered multiple pure math courses) to help.
So my thought -- and again, this is not knowing you or what your circumstances are, so take it with a grain of salt -- is, if possible, to consider improving your circumstances to line up better with your goals.

Due to the rigid system, 1,2 and 3 is not possible. It is outrageous, I know. I am not happy with it.

@Boay Yes, it is possible. I do know an Indian who was in a similar situation. He had to retake the college entrance exam and then got into the department of his preference. Of course, he graduated late. I remember his words to me was "I passed out later than my high school batchmates." something to that effect.
